# How to list icons to the right with text underneath each accordingly?

Tags: html, css, list, twitter-bootstrap, margin

I want to show pictures of icons from left to right and have their respective names underneath each and it spaced. the text "Icon1" underneath icon1 and so on. `tierGo` has no CSS in it.

```
<div id="tierGo">
    <h1>Icon List</h1>
    <img src="tinyIcons/icon1.png" style="margin-right:15px;" />
    <img src="tinyIcons/icon2.png" style="margin-right:15px;" />
    <img src="tinyIcons/icon3.png" style="margin-right:15px;" />
    <img src="tinyIcons/icon4.png" style="margin-right:15px;" />
    <img src="tinyIcons/icon5.png" style="margin-right:15px;" />
</div>
```

Comment: In the code you've shown, there is no caption text. Are you looking for a solution that suggests how to structure and style this, or a solution that adds the text programmatically based on the src?

Comment: yes i need to figure out how to add text to it

Comment: ive tried using <p> but its messy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had success using divs and a list.I also added a bit of CSS to the list.
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cf8ovf04/)

```
<div id="tierGo">
    <h1>Icon List</h1>
    <ul>
   <li> <div image1>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50"/>
        <div >
            Image 1
        </div>
    </div>
   </li>  
   <li> <div image2>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50"/>
        <div >
            Image 2
        </div>
    </div>
   </li>  

   <li> <div image3>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50"/>
        <div >
            Image 3
        </div>
    </div>
   </li>  
    </ul>
```

CSS:

```
li{
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline;
    margin-right: 15px;
    float: left;
}
```